Export/Import Issue: "Root articles must have internal permission"
I'm looking to export Knowledge articles out of Odoo 17 and import them into Odoo 18. When testing before performing the actual import, I receive the following error message:

The file contains blocking errors (see below)


'Root articles must have internal permission.'

For both instances (v17 & v18) I'm logged in as the administrator account when performing the Export/Import functions. I understand that for "root articles", they are more tightly secured (though I can't say I understand the details of how). Attached is an image listing the template I've built for exporting fields.
I've performed a successful export/import process with a more basic list of fields previously (after which I restored the Odoo 18 instance to a database backup before the import). This being the case, it seems that (at least) one of the fields that I've added (between the basic export and this more comprehensive version) may be the cause of the issues, but I'm not sure what that might be.
Two questions:

What field(s) might be contributing to the import error I'm receiving?
Is there a comprehensive list of field descriptions somewhere in the Odoo documentation? (I've not been able to find one as of yet).

Thanks in advance for any guidance you might be able to provide.
Cheers!

(Edited heavily for clarity)
In my question, I'd stated that:

...it seems that (at least) one of the fields that I've added (between the basic export and this more comprehensive version) may be the cause of the issues...

The Odoo export feature (generally, but also specifically for exporting Knowledge articles) provides a long list (really a hierarchy) of fields that a person can export into a flat list (csv, xlsx). I had two sets of fields that I'd chosen. A smaller and a larger list. The export for the smaller list worked, the export for the larger list resulted in the error mentioned above.
The reason that the larger list (with more of the fields I needed to have) was not working was that I had included the "Internal Permission" field in the larger list.
There is evidently a relationship between "root articles" and the "internal permission" field, though I can't precisely define what that relationship is, other than including the "internal permission" field produces an "Root articles must have internal permission" error when it is included.
My expectation would have been that, since I'm logged in as the administrator in both Odoo instances (the "from" server, and the "to" server) that the default value in the "internal permission" field (at least in this case) would indicate to the new server, that root articles do have "internal permission" (permission to create root articles).
Further, it seems that the Root Articles (in my export) have their "internal permission" field set to "Can edit" (I've only validated this with one example article, and am extrapolating here).
I'm not 100% sure why the system behaves exactly as it does, but removing the "internal permission" field allows me to export "root articles" and import them into another system without the attempt resulting in error mentioned in the original question.
Hopefully this helps folks in the future.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
